# How to properly set linker flags on esp-idf projects

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

In trying to port punyforth from esp8266 to esp32, using esp-idf toolchain, I ran unto a linker problem that stumps me.

If not using any special linker flags, I run into errors like:

```
.
.
.
/Users/k/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r1-8.2.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.2.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld: /Users/k/esp/esp-idf/examples/punyforth/arch/esp8266/rtos/user/main/punyforth.S:22:(.irom0.text+0x1237): dangerous relocation: l32r: literal placed after use: (.irom0.literal+0xc)
/Users/k/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r1-8.2.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.2.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld: /Users/k/esp/esp-idf/examples/punyforth/arch/esp8266/rtos/user/main/punyforth.S:24:(.irom0.text+0x123a): dangerous relocation: l32r: literal placed after use: (.irom0.literal+0x10)
/Users/k/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r1-8.2.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.2.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld: /Users/k/esp/esp-idf/examples/punyforth/arch/esp8266/rtos/user/main/punyforth.S:27:(.irom0.text+0x123f): dangerous relocation: l32r: literal placed after use: (.irom0.literal+0x14)
/Users/k/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r1-8.2.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.2.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld: /Users/k/esp/esp-idf/examples/punyforth/arch/esp8266/rtos/user/build/main/libmain.a(punyforth.o): in function `code_divmod':
/Users/k/esp/esp-idf/examples/punyforth/arch/esp8266/rtos/user/main/../../../primitives.S:121:(.irom0.text+0xcd): dangerous relocation: call0: call target out of range: forth_divmod
/Users/k/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r1-8.2.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.2.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld: /Users/k/esp/esp-idf/examples/punyforth/arch/esp8266/rtos/user/build/main/libmain.a(punyforth.o): in function `code_random':
/Users/k/esp/esp-idf/examples/punyforth/arch/esp8266/rtos/user/main/../../../ext.S:388:(.irom0.text+0xb75): dangerous relocation: call0: call target out of range: forth_random
/Users/k/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r1-8.2.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.2.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld: /Users/k/esp/esp-idf/examples/punyforth/arch/esp8266/rtos/user/build/main/libmain.a(punyforth.o): in function `code_usat':
/Users/k/esp/esp-idf/examples/punyforth/arch/esp8266/rtos/user/main/../../../ext.S:525:(.irom0.text+0xf85): dangerous relocation: call0: call target out of range: esp_timer_get_time
```

If I set (like recommended [here](https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=11859&start=20) and in other places)
`LDFLAGS += -mtext-section-literals`, then I get undefined main like so:

```
/Users/k/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r1-8.2.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.2.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld: /Users/k/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r1-8.2.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.2.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/lib/no-rtti/crt0.o:(.literal+0x0): undefined reference to `main'
```

I'm a complete noob regarding the esp-idf toolchain, so I'm pretty much stuck. Any pointers on how to approach this would be great.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532826/what-does-a-dangerous-relocation-error-mean) and [this](https://github.com/SuperHouse/esp-open-rtos/issues/674) post, but I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last error you mention refers to crt0. Peeking into the toolchain provided crt0.0 shows that it expects a symbol "main":

```
xtensa-esp32-elf-objdump -t crt0.o 
crt0.o:     file format elf32-xtensa-le
SYMBOL TABLE:
...
00000000 g       .text  00000000 _start
00000000         *UND*  00000000 main
```

This is why the linker is looking for a symbol "main".

Esp-idf by default [doesn't link](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/cd4fa46f5372a552a67452313d246d4d09d2b39f/make/project.mk#L349) against the standard C library, so specify -nostdlib when building. Unless punyforth itself needs the standard C runtime, then punyforth or your glue code needs to provide "main".